# Super-Left and Super-Right work well but not on a Nautilus window - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, nautilus

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a second laptop (Asus 56C).

Super-Left and Super-Right work well on all windows but not on a Nautilus window.
They work fine on the first laptop, I didn't do anything special for this second install (same applications on both computers ).

Comment: Use F9 to suppress left panel, then Super+arrow, then F9 again to add the panel, works for me.